# Getting width/attributes out of a tag in Beautifulsoup instead of text

Tags: beautifulsoup

So the beautifulsoup documentation I can find talks about finding a specific tag using id, class etc... But it doesn't talk about how to extract data from within the tag rather than what it surrounds.

My issue:

```
<img src=yellowbar.png width=63.94 height=10><img src=redbar.png width=36.0632181423 height=10><br />
Power:</b> 1480 / 1480<br />
<img src=yellowbar.png width=100 height=10><img src=redbar.png width=0 height=10><br />
```

I have this HTML. There are around a total of 20  tags on the page, of which 3 have `src=yellowbar.png`

my goal is, to select the second one, and get the width back. So I am guessing it would go:

Find  tags -> find src=yellowbar.png -> select second one -> print width back.

How would I go about this?

So far I've managed to print a list of all  tags.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(element, "lxml")

tag = soup.find_all('img')
print(tag)
```

which returns

```
[<img height="10" src="yellowbar.png" width="77"/>, <img height="10" src="redbar.png" width="0"/>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I could understand your question then this should solve your issue.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
<img src=yellowbar.png width=63.94 height=10><img src=redbar.png width=36.0632181423 height=10><br />
Power:</b> 1480 / 1480<br />
<img src=yellowbar.png width=100 height=10><img src=redbar.png width=0 height=10><br />
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for tags in soup.find_all("img",{"src":"yellowbar.png"}): #use the attributes as well to specify the item you look for
    print(tags['width']) #access the value using attribute
```

Output:

```
63.94
100
```